# Flexbox sticky footer and container with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where there are left and right columns, with a footer at the bottom. The right column will have overflowing content. I need this container to have the scroll bar and not the whole body so the footer will stay at the bottom and the user will scroll through the right column content.

I also need dynamic height so when the user resizes the window the footer will stay at the bottom and the size of the right column will change. I know I'll need $(window).resize() for this but I'm not sure what exactly to put in the function.

Can someone help me please?

Here's my codepen http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/lmAzb

```
#top {  
  display: flex;

  .left-column {
    background: lightgreen;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .right-column {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    flex-direction: column;    

    header {
      background: coral;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    > div {
      background: lightblue;
      overflow-y: scroll;

      p {   
        padding: 20px;      
      }
    }    

  }

}

.footer {
 flex: 1;
  display: flex;

  .footer-left {
   flex: 1;
   background: pink;
   padding: 20px;
 }

 .footer-right {
   flex: 3;
   background: plum;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign size values based on viewport, that way you can have a bit more control. IN your specific case, I tried this:

```
body{width:100vw; height:100vh; overflow:hidden}
#top {  
  display: flex;

  .left-column {
    background: lightgreen;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    height:85vh;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  .right-column {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:90vh;


    header {
      background: coral;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    > div {
      background: lightblue;
      overflow-y: scroll;

      p {   
        padding: 20px;      
      }
    }    

  }

}

.footer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
 height:10vh;

  .footer-left {
    flex: 1;
    background: pink;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .footer-right {
    flex: 3;
    background: plum;
  }

}
```

and it seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. I [forked your codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dewpb) so you can see it, but since CodePen uses iframes and viewport sizes don't work fine with iframes, you'll need to test on a real page by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Set the outer container (the body) to be a flexbox parent and set the direction to flow down vertically so you can fix the footer to the bottom.

Here's a quick and dirty solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uzexD

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```